# Why is the phrase "¡Hasta la próxima!" feminine?

Tags: género

## Español

Trad. de la pregunta: ¿Por qué es femenina la frase "¡Hasta la próxima!"?

En la frase "¡hasta la próxima!, ¿por qué el género es femenino en lugar de masculino? ¿Es el género arbitrario, o tiene que ver con algún sustantivo femenino omitido?

---

## Inglés

In the phrase, "¡Hasta la próxima!", why is the gender feminine instead of masculine? Is the gender arbitrary, or is there a specific omitted feminine noun that's implied?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Español

Porque es la forma abreviada de:

> Hasta la próxima vez.

Y "*vez*" es femenino.

---

## Inglés

Because that is a shortened form of

> Hasta la próxima vez.

And "*vez*" is feminine.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. También puede ser para "hasta la próxima ocasión (de vernos)"